# How do disable CSRF for the specific origin

Tags: spring-boot, maven, authentication, swagger, csrf

I needed to add auth in Swagger, but I have no idea how to pass the CSRF token to each request. If I disabled the CSRF token protection then it works fine, but its not a solution, so now I need to disable CSRF for this specific origin

```
  @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**","/v2/api-docs","/swagger-     ui/**","/auth/**","/user","/csrf")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(malformedTokenHandler, LogoutFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
```

I also have SwaggerConfig class like this:

```
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()))
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey()))
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("JWT", "Authorization", "header");
    }
 
    List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        AuthorizationScope authorizationScope
                = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
        authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
        return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("JWT", authorizationScopes));
    }
 
 private List<Parameter> operationParameters(CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository) {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        CsrfToken csrfToken = csrfTokenRepository.loadToken(request);
        return Arrays.asList(
                new ParameterBuilder()
                        .name("X-CSRF-TOKEN")
                        .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
                        .parameterType("header")
                        .defaultValue(csrfToken.getToken())
                        .required(false)
                        .build());
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/swagger-resources/**","/v2/api-docs","/swagger-ui/**")
```

But still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(yourCsrfMatcher)
```

and you'll find the documention for the class RequestMatcher [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatcher.html):

```
public class YourCsrfMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
    @override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request){
         // add your logic here and return false for the specific origin
         return true;
    }  
}
```